# How to deal with different Bluetooth stacks on Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth, drivers

I'm trying to write a simple Bluetooth SPP driver and I was wondering what are the best practices to deal with different Bluetooth stacks - Widcomm, Microsoft, Toshiba etal. From the initial research I'm not sure how one can discover the Bluetooth serial ports for all these stacks programmatically. Fog eg. if a BT device uses COM5 & COM6 how can one look it up for each of the stack how the device was paired.

Comment: I've had nothing but misery and failure with Bluetooth.  Lord is it screwed up.  Run man, run!

Answer (score -1):

I've been successfully using this [library](http://www.btframework.com/bt.htm) it is called WCL but it is not free. With this you can connect through SPP without requiring to create a virtual COM port.

While their documentation is not very good, they provide some good demo code that you may want to try.

Comment: No I've no relationship with those guys. I just spent a lot of time searching for such a librairy that I think it is helpful to share this information. I can erase my posts if it becomes such an annoyment for you